# index not being used

Tags: mysql, index

I have an exact same myisam table on master and slave. The indexes are not being used on Master server.

```
mysql> explain select count(date_time) from ox_data_summary_ad_hourly where  date_time = '2012-03-08 00:00:00' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ox_data_summary_ad_hourly
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 32212292
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The explain plan on the slave:

```
mysql> explain select count(date_time) from ox_data_summary_ad_hourly where  date_time = '2012-03-08 00:00:00' \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ox_data_summary_ad_hourly
         type: ref
possible_keys: ox_data_summary_ad_hourly_date_time
          key: ox_data_summary_ad_hourly_date_time
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 156769
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The master is 5.0 while slave is on 5.5 version if that matters.

Does it mean the index file on master is corrupt?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a bug report for this for 5.5. Trying to find it...

Comment: @gbn: It is not using the index on the 5.0 machine. And the `possible_keys: NULL` means that there is no index in the table in that machine, doesn't it?

Comment: @ypercube: good point, should be answer...

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE ox_data_summary_ad_hourly\G` on Master and Slave. If they are different, please post them both in your question.

Comment: Both are "exactly" the same tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual rule of thumb for MySQL Query Optimizer is this:

If the EXPLAIN plan has to read more than 5% of the table rows via the index, the index is dismissed (ruled out) and a full table scan is performed.

In the case of the Slave, 156769 out of 32212292 rows are to be read. That's 0.4867%. Hence, the index is used.

With regard to the Master, it is very disturbing that the MySQL Query Optimizer ruled out indexes. As @ypercube commented, perhaps there is no index.

You should make sure by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE ox_data_summary_ad_hourly\G` on both Master and Slave. If they are different, please post both outputs in the question.

Also, please run `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ox_data_summary_ad_hourly;` on both Master and Slave and post these counts

Comment: Hmm, so is it generally recommended to use `force key` to stop mysql from second-guessing?

Comment: @Pacerier sometimes blindly using FORCE INDEX without know the cardinality of individual key values can make things worse. Character sets can also hide why FORCE INDEX can fail See http://www.mysqldiary.com/the-battle-between-force-index-and-the-query-optimizer/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860113/mysql-force-index-doesnt-work and http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/08/why-index-could-refuse-to-work/ as to why

Comment: Btw regarding the second link, [I can't seem to reproduce the error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719392/why-isnt-mysql-using-any-of-these-possible-keys/5826874#comment44893952_5826874). Are you aware  if the bug has been fixed for good?